Using BibTeX in a masterdocument
I am trying to cite a reference within a sub-document included in a master document, but I encounter the following warnings:
Citation 'reference' undefined.
Empty 'thebibliography' environment.
There were undefined references.

The citation works perfectly when I use \cite{reference} directly in the master document, but it fails when I place the same citation command in the sub-document.
Master document:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{title}
\author{author}
\begin{document}

\include{part1}

\bibliography{References}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\end{document}

Sub-document (part 1.tex)
This is to be cited /cite{reference}.

References.bib
@misc{reference,
    author       = {{author}},
    title        = {title},
}


This issue has been resolved.


Related: When should I use \input vs. \include?

So you really use \cite, not /cite as showed here. Also you can safely remove  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} with the actual LaTeX versions.

This issue has been resolved.
\input{part1} should be used in place of \include{part1}.

Welcome to TeX. You can accept this answer by clicking on the green checkmark. This way, this problem will be considered solved.
